# List all the ancestors or parent nodes of a particular node present at each level in pivoted table containing levels as attributes in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot, hierarchy, recursive-cte

I have a table 'temp' which has id and its immediate parent's id as columns. The table is as follows:

[image: temp table]

```
                              1
                            /   \
                           2     3
                          /|\     \
                         4 5 6     7
                        /
                       8
```

Hierarchy of nodes can be represented in tree structure as above.

Now, I want to list all the ancestor or parent nodes of each node present at all levels in pivoted table using **recursive cte** which has levels (like Level1, Level2 and so on) as its attributes. To get this output, I have calculated all the parent nodes in non pivoted table with level of each node with respect to its parent. The sql query for which is below:

```
WITH ctetable as 
(
    SELECT S.id, S.parent, 1 as level
    FROM temp as S where S.parent is not null
    UNION ALL
    SELECT S2.id, p.parent, p.level + 1
    FROM ctetable AS p JOIN temp as S2 on S2.parent = p.id
)
SELECT * FROM ctetable ORDER BY id;
```

The output of above query is shown below:

[image: cte output]

But, I want to pivot the recursive cte which contains the parent id under at each level of a particular node. Say, for id=4, it should display parent id 4, 2 and 1 under Level3, Level2 and Level1 respectively. For this I wrote the following query:

```
WITH ctetable as 
(
    SELECT S.id, S.parent, 1 as level
    FROM temp as S where S.parent is not null
    UNION ALL
    SELECT S2.id, p.parent, p.level + 1
    FROM ctetable AS p JOIN temp as S2 on S2.parent = p.id
)

SELECT      
            myid,
            [pn].[1] AS [Level1],
            [pn].[2] AS [Level2],
            [pn].[3] AS [Level3] 
FROM
     (
         SELECT [a].id,
                [a].id as myid,
                [a].level
         FROM ctetable AS [a]
     ) AS [hn] PIVOT(max([hn].id) FOR [hn].level IN([1],[2],[3])) AS [pn]
```

But, the output table is not the desired one as it contains the same id repeated as parent id under each level for a particular node instead it should contain all the parents of that node under various levels. The output i got after executing the above query is shown below:

[image: main output]

Can anybody help me out with this....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a known or maximum number of levels, and assuming I did not reverse your desired results.

**Also** Best if you post sample data and desired results as text, not as an image

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([id] int,[parent] int)
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,null)
,(2,1)
,(3,1)
,(7,3)
,(4,2)
,(5,2)
,(6,2)
,(8,4)

;with cteP as (
      Select id
            ,Parent 
            ,PathID = cast(10000+id as varchar(500))
      From   @YourTable
      Where  Parent is Null
      Union  All
      Select id  = r.id
            ,Parent  = r.Parent 
            ,PathID = cast(concat(p.PathID,',',10000+r.id) as varchar(500))
      From   @YourTable r
      Join   cteP p on r.Parent  = p.id)
Select ID
      ,B.*
 From  cteP A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Level1 = xDim.value('/x[1]','int')-10000
                      ,Level2 = xDim.value('/x[2]','int')-10000
                      ,Level3 = xDim.value('/x[3]','int')-10000
                      ,Level4 = xDim.value('/x[4]','int')-10000
                      ,Level5 = xDim.value('/x[5]','int')-10000
                From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace(PathID,',','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as X 
             ) B
  Order By PathID
```

**Returns**

[image]

**EDIT - Added +10000**

I added the +10000 so that the sequence will be maintained

Comment: Is there any other approach which do not use xml and can be done with pivot? It somewhat looks more complex with xml, replace and value method.

Comment: @RajatSaini I'm sure there is, but the XML portion is just parsing a delimited string.  If your IDs and parents are truly INTs, you can use the datatype hierarchyid but the performance may suffer.   Furthermore, the CROSS APPLY allows for lateral queries.